# Presenting new ViewController from different storyboard - strange delay

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have noticed strange behaviour.
When i'm presenting new viewController that is initiated programatically from different storyboard and flag animated is set to YES there is huge delay before ViewController is shown.

```
        UINavigationController * enterVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Survey_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"echoEntryVC"];
        [self presentViewController:enterVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

When flag is set to NO view Controller is presented immediately.

```
        UINavigationController * enterVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Survey_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"echoEntryVC"];
        [self presentViewController:enterVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Does someone have the same problem? Any explanation would be good :)

Comment: Any chance your view controller is doing some heavy duty operations in `viewWill/DidAppear` if animated == YES?

Comment: no it's just blank controller

Comment: Is there a problem with having them in the same storyboard? Generally projects only need two storyboards, one for iPhone screen sizes and one for iPad screen sizes.